# How to enable php extensions when using the image php:7.2-apache with docker-compose?

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

I want to run a apache webserver with php extension inside container using docker compose as deployment.

My compose  file looks like this:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  php:
    image: php:7.2-apache
    ports:
      - 8089:80
    volumes:
      - ./php/www:/var/www/html/
```

how can I enable the following extensions.

```
 apache2
 php7.2
 php-xdebug
 php7.2-mcrypt
 php-apcu
 php-apcu-bc
 php7.2-json
 php-imagick
 php-gettext
 php7.2-mbstring
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all you can run `php -m` in `php` container to see installed and enabled modules.

You can edit your `docker-compose.yml` like this:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  php:
    # image: php:7.2-apache # remember to comment this line
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8089:80
    volumes:
      - ./php/www:/var/www/html/
```

Create a file called `Dockerfile` beside `docker-compose.yml` with the following contents:

```
FROM php:7.2-apache
# then add the following `RUN ...` lines in each separate line, like this:
RUN pecl install xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
...
```

Finally, let's go one by one:

### apache2

Is installed.

### php7.2

Is enabled.

### php-xdebug

Add `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN pecl install xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
```

### php7.2-mcrypt

Add to `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN apt-get install libmcrypt-dev
RUN pecl install mcrypt && docker-php-ext-enable mcrypt
```

### php-apcu

Add to `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN pecl install apcu && docker-php-ext-enable apcu
```

### php-apcu-bc

Add to `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN pecl install apcu_bc
RUN cp /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-production /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
RUN echo 'extension=apc.so' >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
```

### php7.2-json

Is installed.

### php-imagick

Add to `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN apt install -y libmagickwand-dev --no-install-recommends && \
    pecl install imagick && docker-php-ext-enable imagick
```

### php-gettext

Add to `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN docker-php-ext-install gettext && \
    docker-php-ext-enable gettext
```

### php7.2-mbstring

Is enabled.

Comment: How easy it was to understand with this step by step. I searched some materials, but his post was worth everything I had researched Thank you

Comment: I would add this quote from official docs: "It is strongly recommended that users use an explicit version number in their pecl install invocations to ensure proper PHP version compatibility (PECL does not check the PHP version compatibility when choosing a version of the extension to install, but does when trying to install it)".